# How to enhance 'this' with type safety in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance

This code works good in vanilla javascript

```js
const enhancementA = {
    a() {
        return this.c + 1;
    },
};

const enhancementB = {
    b() {
        return this.c + 2;
    },
};

class C {
    c = 0;
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, enhancementA, enhancementB);
    }
}

const d = new C();

d.a() // 1
d.b() // 2
d.c // 0
```

But it doesn't work in typescript

```js
d.a() // TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'C'.
d.b() // TS2339: Property 'b' does not exist on type 'C'.
```

How can I make it work in typescript ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the C class can remain as-is due to the dynamic addition of `enhancementA` and `enhancementB`, which don't exist on C and so can't be returned from the constructor (or mutated onto the instance with type support). I'd make a function that returns an object combined with the enhancements instead.

A type parameter can be used to indicate that `this` must be an object with a numeric `c` property.

```
const enhancementA = {
    a<T extends { c: number }>(this: T) {
        return this.c + 1;
    },
};

const enhancementB = {
    b<T extends { c: number }>(this: T) {
        return this.c + 2;
    },
};

const makeC = () => {
    return {
        c: 0,
        ...enhancementA,
        ...enhancementB
    };
};

const d = makeC();

d.a() // 1
d.b() // 2
d.c // 0
```

This produces an object of the type

```
{
    b<T extends { c: number; }>(this: T): number;
    a<T extends { c: number; }>(this: T): number;
    c: number;
}
```